# How to make a function that makes a request every second in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a function and I want to request this function again every second. How can I do that?

For example

```
getMessage(){}
```

I want to send a request to this function every second and see if there are new messages. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Timer.periodic`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) for that:

```dart
Timer.periodic(
  const Duration(seconds: 1), 
  (timer) => getMessage(),
);
```